# Why isn't there a protected access modifier in F#?

Tags: f#

Is there a better way of modeling data in F# to avoid needing it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `protected` modifier can be quite problematic in F#, because you often need to call members from a lambda expression. However, when you do that, you no longer access the method from within the class. This also causes confusion when using protected members declared in C# (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366490/f-how-to-access-protected-member)). If you could declare a `protected` member, the following code could be surprising:

```
type Base() = 
  protected member x.Test(a) = a > 10

type Inherited() = 
  inherit Base()
  member x.Filter(list) =
    list |> List.filter (fun a -> x.Test(a))
```

This code wouldn't work, because you're calling `Test` from a lambda function (which is a different object than the current instance of `Test`), so the code wouldn't work. I think this is tha main reason for not supporting the `protected` modifier in F#.

In F# you typically use implementation inheritance (that is, inheriting from a base class) much less frequently than in C#, so you shouldn't need `protected` as often. Instead, it is usually preferred to use interfaces (in the object-oriented F# code) and higher-order functions (in the functional code). However, it is difficult to say how to avoid the need for `protected` in general (other than by avoiding implementation inheritance). Do you have some specific example which motivated your question?

Comment: This is true, but it's an implementation artifact of the compiler.  There's no fundamental reason that an F#-like .NET language couldn't generate a nested class to house the closure and have the intended semantics.

Comment: Good explanation. It's easy to forget about objects the F# compiler creates to support lambdas and other functional constructs. I'm writing an ORM that will be used frequently from C#. It uses something of a provider model. There's an abstract Repository class, which might be extended by SqlRepository, OracleRepository, etc. I wanted a protected method that loads schema information for a table. Any ideas of a better way to do this?

Comment: @kvb - I thought the same thing. Is there a way the compiler could check if a protected member is being accessed from a lambda in a derived class?

Comment: See this blog post by Eric Lippert (http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2005/11/14/why-are-base-class-calls-from-anonymous-delegates-nonverifiable.aspx) for a discussion of how a similar problem caused the C# compiler to emit unverifiable code previously, although the code-gen approach has been changed to fix this in C# 4.

Comment: It may be just an implementation artifact of the compiler, but it's a question whether allowing this would be an expected behavior. For example you could easily write a member that returns lambda function, which calls the `protected` member. I belive this is against the principle of `protected` members. In general, I think that the notion of protected members just doesn't work very well with functional features and since F# is still mostly a functional language, this is a logical trade-off.

Comment: @Tomas - I agree with the second half of your comment: I can't remember ever missing `protected` members when using F#.  As to the first half of your comment, though, I don't see this as any different than exposing a public member which wraps a protected member.  C#'s approach seems very intuitive to me, and I haven't seen any complaints/confusion around it.

Comment: This is one of those places where F# guys don't feel any compassion for C# folks. Of course it can be implemented, but as in c#, the F# language reached a certain stage where the authors (main contributors) don't want to add anything even if it is obviously missing. Another example: type inference in F# is cool, but incomplete, you can achieve clever hacks though, but you cannot do it simple and explicitly: overloading module operators or module functions, using unicode chars for custom operators.

Comment: Exactly @Liviu when I asked about this on twitter I received the answer that "although F# support object orientation it does so in an opinionated way". I think that's a lot closer to the real reason F# doesn't support defining protected members: Someone who doesn't write a lot of object oriented code doesn't think it's important. Unfortunately without support for protected F# cannot be considered a first-class citizen in .NET.

Answer (score 8):

As to whether F# enables a better way of modeling data, signature files allow finer grained visibility decisions than `internal` does in C#, which is often very nice.  See Brian's comment [here](http://fpish.net/topic/None/59219#comment-70220) for a little bit more explanation.  This is independent of support (or lack thereof) for `protected`, though.

Comment: link seems dead

Comment: @Maslow - Thanks for pointing this out; I've updated the link to what I think is a mirror of the original post.