# protected virtual methods in f#

Tags: f#, virtual, abstract, protected

- F# does not support the definition of `protected` methods. Here it is explained [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390515/why-isnt-there-a-protected-access-modifier-in-f)
- F# replaces `virtual`methods with `abstract`methods defined in abstract classes (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233225.aspx)).

I was wondering if there is a way to prevent access to `abstract` methods from outside the derived classes at all.

Comment: I don't think it's possible - you're effectively asking if there's a way to make method `protected`, which is not supported. :) Maybe there's a different approach to the problem you're trying to solve, although we'd probably need more details.

Comment: Well, I suppose the question says it all. However, I deemed it a question worth asking: there may exist a creative workaround out there.

Comment: Would `internal` work for your purposes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Patryk Ćwiek, I also don't think it's possible, but here's one alternative:

From [Design Patterns](http://amzn.to/XBYukB) we know that we should **favour Composition over Inheritance**. In my experience, everything you can do with Inheritance, you can also do with Composition. As an example, you can always replace Template Method with a Strategy.

A Template Method is a typical use of an abstract method, but if you replace it with a Strategy, you can (sort of) hide it from clients:

```
type Foo(strategy : IBar) =
    member this.CreateStuff() =
        // 1. Do something concrete here
        // 2. Use strategy for something here
        // 3. Do something else concrete here
        // 4. Return a result
```

No outside client of `Foo` can invoke `strategy`, so that accomplishes the same goal as making a member protected.

You may argue that the original creator of `Foo` may keep a reference to `strategy`, and will still be able to invoke it. That's true, but protected members aren't really completely hidden either, because you can often derive from the class in question, which enables you to invoke the protected member.

Another point is that if you separate the creator of `Foo` from the client of `Foo`, the `strategy` will be unavailable to the client.