# call abstract function from a method's own implementation

Tags: f#, abstract

I have tried to call an [abstract](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483471.aspx) function from a method's own implementation.

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type CallAnAbstract () = 

    let doSomethingElse () = printfn "Done Something.."

    abstract doSomethingAbstract: unit -> unit

    member this.DoSomething =
        printfn "Done Something.."
        doSomethingElse ()
        doSomethingAbstract ()
```

which results in the error:

> error FS0039: The value or constructor 'doSomethingAbstract' is not
>   defined

Is calling an abstract function from a method's own implementation illegal or does the problem lie somewhere else?

If that being illegal is the case,
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221367/protected-virtual-methods-in-f?noredirect=1#comment33752069_22221367) (see answer) @Mark Seemann explains composition over inheritance:

```
[<AbstractClass>]
type UseComposition (doSomethingElseDefinedLater) = 

    let doSomethingElse () = printfn "Done Something.."

    member this.DoSomething =
        printfn "Done Something.."
        doSomethingElse ()
        doSomethingElseDefinedLater ()
```

What are the alternatives? I'd avoid passing the function via constructor and I'd like to reuse the some code, having `DoSomething` have "some implementation" until the call to the abstract function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `this` reference:

```
this.doSomethingAbstract()
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks. I thought only `members` required to be referenced that way.

Comment: It is an `abstract` _member_.

Comment: It is `private` and it has not been declared using `abstract member`. Isn't that an `abstract` *method*?

Comment: Not sure of the precise definition, but I suspect anything defined with the keyword `member` is a member. That would include properties and methods.

Comment: Well, `abstract doSomethingAbstract: unit -> unit` is not declared with the keyword `member` and behaves differently than `abstract member doSomethingAbstract: unit -> unit`. I am not sure either how to refer to `doSomethingAbstract` as per the first definition.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `let doSomethingElse () = printfn "Done Something.."` does not require a `this` reference.

Comment: My mistake: `abstract doSomethingAbstract: unit -> unit` and  `abstract member doSomethingAbstract: unit -> unit` are indeed the same.

Comment: `let` bindings can't be called with a `this` reference, only members. True, an `abstract` member definition doesn't include the keyword `member`, but an override or default implementation does.