# F# and protected access modifier

Tags: f#, functional-programming, access-modifiers

You can't define protected class members in F# due in part to how they complicate the functional nature of the language. (The Book of F# - Dave Fancher).

I am new to functional programming, and the book does not explain details about it. So, how exactly they complicate the functional paradigm? Can anyone explain it better?

Comment: Here's a plausible explanation why using protected would be a pain: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390515/why-isnt-there-a-protected-access-modifier-in-f

Comment: In short, it's more the other way round: functional nature of the language would complicate using `protected` if the language had it.

Comment: Yet another view on the same thing: Access level modifiers were invented to overcome certain OOP-related problems. Not to say that FP has no problems at all, they are, but different to the OOP's. Hence, `protected` appears to be merely useless in F# (plus it takes an effort to maintain).

Comment: Never thought about the lambda problem. Interesting. Thanks for the link.