# Access parent field privately

Tags: inheritance, f#, access-control

In the following code I can access the field `a` in `Parent` from `Child` via the member `A`:

```ml
type Parent () =
    let a = 5
    member _.A = a

type Child () =
    inherit Parent ()
    let b = base.A
```

This makes `a` accessible everywhere. Is there a way to make `a` accessible from inheriting classes like `Child` and its children, but otherwise private to `Parent`?

Comment: Seems like you're asking [Why isn't there a protected access modifier in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390515/why-isnt-there-a-protected-access-modifier-in-f)