# F# Inherit from C# class + access protected fields

Tags: inheritance, f#, protected

I have this base class that creates a new SQL Server connection and does some utility methods in C#, I want to inherit in F#. Currently I cannot access the protected fields in the C# class from F#, although this would work in C#.

C# abstract class

```cs
public abstract class SQL
{
    protected readonly SqlConnectionStringBuilder bld;
    protected readonly SqlCommand cmd;
    protected readonly SqlConnection conn;
    protected readonly string connstring;
    protected string userid;

    public SQL(string server, string db)
    {
        bld = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
        bld.DataSource = server;
        bld.InitialCatalog = db;
        bld.IntegratedSecurity = true;
        connstring = bld.ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(connstring);
        cmd = new SqlCommand();

        GetUserID();
        //Other utility methods here
    }
```

F# code to inherit

```
type Transfer ( server : string ) ( db : string ) = 
inherit SQL(server, db)  
let accessAbstractConn = conn. //Can't access protected field????
```

Have I missed something here? I have tried aliasing the base class field e.g. this.conn which also does not work.

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can add a self-identifier to the constructor:

```
type Transfer ( server : string, db : string ) as this = 
  inherit SQL(server, db)  
  let accessAbstractConn = this.conn
```

or, use the `base` keyword:

```
type Transfer ( server : string, db : string ) = 
  inherit SQL(server, db)  
  let accessAbstractConn = base.conn
```

Answer (score 2):

See related questions:

- [F# - How to access protected member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2366490/562906)
- [Why isn't there a protected access modifier in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390591/562906)

Basically I think you can't do it from within a `let` because it's actually in the context of an implicit lambda.

Comment: Yes it seems so, looking at Daniel's code calling the class with an alias does give access to all members including inherited members. However I cannot access the fields. So how can I change the properties of say, the connection field?

Comment: @RichardTodd: The two approaches in my answer provide access to _all_ protected members, including fields.