# Access protected const from base class in attribute

Tags: c#, f#, xunit

I have a base class with a constant

```
public class TestClassBase
{
    protected const string Foo = "Bar";
}
```

which I can consume in C# as follows

```
[Trait(Foo, "")]
public class MyCSharpTestClass : TestClassBase
{
}
```

How do I consume it in a F# class? `Foo` is not recognized by the compiler.

```
[<Trait(Foo, "")>]
type MyFSharpTestClass() =
  inherit TestClassBase()
```

The error I get is: FS0267 This is not a valid constant expression or custom attribute value.

**EDIT**

`[<Trait(Foo, "")>]` yields: FS0039 The value or constructor 'Foo' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: floor.

`[<Trait(this.Foo, "")>]` yields FS0039 The value, namespace, type or module 'this' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: ThisAssembly.

`[<Trait(base.Foo, "")>]` yields FS0039 The value, namespace, type or module 'base' is not defined. Maybe you want one of the following: Base.

`[<Trait(TestClassBase.Foo, "")>]` yields FS0039 The field, constructor or member 'Foo' is not defined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091468/f-inherit-from-c-sharp-class-access-protected-fields

Comment: Have you tried it qualified, like `TestClassBase.Foo`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin see my edit. Your suggestion did not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was classified as a bug on the [Github site](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/3172).