# F# access protected field from a C# inherited class

Tags: c#, f#

I have a class in C# which looks like this:

```
class A {
    protected SomeClass Field;
}

class B: A {}
```

and following code in F#:

```
type C() =
    inherit B()

    member this.SomeMethod() =
        let magic() = base.Field.SomeMoreMagic(someParam) //this.Field also fails
        ...
```

in which I want to access the protected field `Field`. I know that I could access protected fields from class B by simple type `base.something` ([which is also answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091468/f-inherit-from-c-sharp-class-access-protected-fields)) but when I type `base.Field` to access protected field from class **A** I get an error that `struct or class field is not accessible from this code location`, because `Field` is declared in class A(?). 
My question is, is there some possibility to access it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [F# Inherit from C# class + access protected fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15091468/f-inherit-from-c-sharp-class-access-protected-fields). Looks like using the first part of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15092122/3872935) solves the problem.

Comment: @Kote nope, solution provided there is correct if I have field declared in B class instead of class A.

Comment: Actually, I can't reproduce your problem at all. If I use the exact code you show (but with a valid method body), I get `'base' values may only be used to make direct calls to the base implementations of overridden members`. If I write the code correctly, as `this.Field` instead of `base.Field`, it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a resolution to my problem.
Code like this is incorrect:

```
type C() =
    inherit B()

    member this.SomeMethod() =
        let d() = base.Field.SomeMagic(someParameter) //this.Field also fails
        d()
```

but code like this works correctly:

```
type C() =
    inherit B()

    member this.SomeMethod() =
        let stub = this.Field
        let d() = stub.SomeMagic(someParameter)
        d()
```

Comment: Edited to make bodies of the methods unambiguous (and change downvote into an upvote).

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your stub workaround works is because you're trying to access the protected field within the body of a let-bound function `d`. Such functions are moved outside of the context they're defined in and compiled into subtypes of `FSharpFunc` type. That is, you get something like this in the compiled F# code (simplified picture):

```
internal class d@11 : FSharpFunc<Unit, int>
{
    public C @this;

    internal d@11(C @this)
    {
        this.@this = @this;
    }

    public override int Invoke(Unit unitVar0)
    {
        // this would be an attempt to access the protected field 
        // if the compiler allowed it.
        return @this.Field.SomeMoreMagic();  
    }
}

public class C : B
{
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        FSharpFunc<Unit, int> d = new d@11(this);
        return d.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

Which means that the block of code where you tried to access the protected field is no longer part of class `C`, and `protected` modifier prevents access there.

Whereas if you bind the value outside of `d`, you get something like this:

```
public class C : B
{
    public int SomeMethod()
    {
        SomeClass stub = this.Field;
        FSharpFunc<Unit, int> d = new d@11(stub);
        return d.Invoke(null);
    }
}
```

and no protected access happens outside class `C` anymore.

Comment: @MNie: sure, felt obliged to give one after I got tricked by your example. ;)