# Property 'Context' is static error in F#

Tags: c#, f#, static-members, akka.net

I have a problem with rewriting following Akka.Net actor from C# to F#:

```
public class Listener : ReceiveActor
{
    public Listener()
    {
        Receive<Messages.Shutdown>(s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"shutdown {s.Duration}");
            Context.System.Terminate();
        });
    }
}
```

Actor should handle only Shutdown message by terminating actor system. I tried to reimplement it like this:

```ml
type Listener() =
    inherit ReceiveActor()
    do
        base.Receive<Messages>(fun m -> 
            match m with 
            | Shutdown(duration) -> 
                printf "shutdown %s" (duration.ToString())
                base.Context.System.Terminate()
                true
            | _ -> false)
```

but there is a complation error in line `base.Context.System.Terminate()` saying `Property 'Context' is static`. What is wrong with this code? Why can't I access static property of a baseclass? Is it because this code is in lambda expresion (fun)? Or because it is in constructor (do)?

Comment: "*Why can't I access static property of a baseclass?*" Who said you couldn't? You just can't access it through an instance – try `ActorBase.Context`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out. Problems were:

1. I used wrong syntax for accessing static member of base class. As @ildjarn commented, it shuld be `ReceiveActor.Context`, not `base.Context`.
2. Protected member cannot be accessed from lambda expression. Handler needs to be a member method.

Working version:

```
type Listener() as this =
    inherit ReceiveActor()
    do
        base.Receive<Messages>(this.handle)

    member this.handle(message: Messages): bool = 
        match message with 
        | Shutdown(duration) -> 
            printf "shutdown %s" (duration.ToString())
            ReceiveActor.Context.System.Terminate()
            true
        | _ -> false
```

Important changes: 1. `as this` lets us call member method from constructor, 2. type annotations in `handle` method are needed for compiler to resolve `Receive` method overloading ambiguity.

Comment: +1 for figuring out the rest. Have a look at the other details and note that you're still using ``base`` in your code.

Answer (score 5):

You can write it like this:

```
type Listener() =
    inherit ReceiveActor()
    do
        base.Receive<Messages>(fun m -> 
            match m with 
            | Shutdown(duration) -> 
                printf "shutdown %s" (duration.ToString())
                ReceiveActor.Context.System.Terminate()
                true
            | _ -> false)
```

Note that here you can use `function` instead of `match` ...`with`:

```
        base.Receive<Messages>(function 
            | Shutdown(duration) ->
```

Then `printfn` is the equivalent of WriteLine and this:

```
printfn "shutdown %s" (duration.ToString())
```

is the same as:

```
printfn "shutdown %O" duration
```

**UPDATE**

If it is a static property as your error message says, you can't use it from a lambda, for that issue see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366490/how-to-access-protected-member) already answered question.

Comment: `ReceiveActor.Context.System.Terminate()` does not work. It gives an error saying that I can not access protected member in lambda expression.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it's protected. Then you can't use the lambda and the ``function`` keyword. The other changes still apply.